# unable to use variable in SSIS script task

Tags: c#, json, dll, ssis

I have an SSIS package that uses a script task to dynamically load a DLL. It works when I hard-code the file path to the string variable `path`:

**WORKING**

```
namespace ST_0a8ce4d87e1c40b4a7bbf7bd3be96cbc.csproj
{
[System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

    public ScriptMain()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    public Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft"))
        {
            string path = @"\\path\to\DLL\Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
            return Assembly.LoadFile(path);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

}

But when I try and replace the line:

`string path = @"\\path\to\DLL\Newtonsoft.Json.dll";`

with:

`string path = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath_JsonDLL"].Value.ToString();`

Where the variable value is `\\path\to\DLL\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, the package errors out and says that it can load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'? I'm not sure why this would work with a hard-coded value but not a variable?

**UPDATE - ADDING ERROR MESSAGE**

```
    Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
    File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0010009): The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100.get_Item(Object Index)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   at ST_0a8ce4d87e1c40b4a7bbf7bd3be96cbc.csproj.ScriptMain.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(String assemblyFullName)
   at ST_6d9e84ae1c284668ac5306f36b3f5f36.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()


   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: your use of Dts.Variables looks right but have you allowed the script task to read or read/write from the variable?  Also are you sure the variable has a value?  Can you provide the exact error?

Comment: The variable has a value and is setup as read-only for the script task. I have added the error statement to the original post.

Comment: The error makes it look like you are missing a dependency of the assembly/library which I am not sure why it would work hard coded vs not.... I would try throwing and error right before Assembly.LoadFile and see what the actual value of your variable is.

Comment: throw new Exception(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath_JsonDLL"].value.ToString()) ? "IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace" : Dts.Variables["User::FilePath_JsonDLL"].value.ToString());